# Julia version in Julia Studio

Tags: julia, julia-studio

(a) I have Julia Studio 0.4.3 and the settings for libraries in my installation (Windows) point to `C:/Program Files (x86)/JuliaStudio-0.4.3/julia-studio/Julia`. Within that directory, I found `julia-basic.exe`, `julia-debug.exe`, `julia-debug-readline.exe` and `julia-readline.exe`. I didn't find `julia.exe` in that folder.

If I write a Julia file within Julia studio, but later I want to run it in `cmd` line or a `bat` file, which `exe` should I use?

Do I need to install Julia separately if I want to run Julia from `cmd` line or a `bat` file (Windows)?

(b) Also the Julia documentation says that I can start Julia with `-p n` option (where `n` is the number of workers). Is it possible to do this within Julia Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia Studio uses the `julia-basic` executable.  There is no `julia` executable, *per se*.  Rather there is `julia-basic` and `julia-readline` executables, the later of which has [GNU Readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) capabilities. The debug versions of the executables included [debug symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) in the executable--it does not sound like you need those.

You can add processors in the REPL with `addprocs` ([link to docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.addprocs)).  There is no requirement to define the number of processors up front when starting the Julia process.